# How to get a server's clock time by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

That server's clock time is different with my computer clock time and I need to do a function due to server's clock time. How can I get the server's clock time and pass it to my `schedule` module with Python? I have written all it's needed and just time is remained and I'm so confused how to do that.

**Note:** I'm not admin of the server.

Comment: can you add what operating system the server is running? is it linux based?

Comment: @Samiser I don't know. How can I detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `request` module and getting *'Date Related'* HTTP header.

```
server_result = req.get('URL...')
print(server_result.headers['Date-Related...'])
```